# Woocommerce Products Widget for a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, product

How can I make the Woocommerce Products Widget display Products of a specific Category only? Current options are on-sale, featured, and all.

Comment: Do you know where are those values coming from? Code or Database?

I would bet that it is DB and you will need to make an addition into the DB. Which can probably be done through the admin site.

Comment: @TylerChristian - They are in the code.  OP will have to create your own widget, modify code, or pay for one of the existing "products by category" widgets that are out there.

Comment: This is a site designed for developers, asking developer-related questions.  If you want help developing / coding this, you'll need to show what you tried, and what didn't work about it.  Please read the "How to Ask" portion of the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_products_widget_query_args`** filter hook. You will have to set inside it, in the array, your product category (or your product categories if more than one).

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    // Set HERE your product category slugs 
    $categories = array( 'music', 'posters' );

    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $categories,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested in WooCommerce 3+ and works

Comment: This worked perfectly. 
I tried to alter the woocommerce plugin itself but ended up going with your solution !! thanks

Answer (score 0):

To show products from **current** category, something like this works:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $cat_slug = $category->slug;
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $cat_slug,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```