# WooCommerce products widget for a specific category - set category array per widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I had the same question as Quadie as answered in the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184153/woocommerce-products-widget-for-a-specific-category).

The code as provided by LoicTheAztec works great...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function( $query_args ){
    // Set HERE your product category slugs 
    $categories = array( 'music', 'posters' );

    $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $categories,
    ));

    return $query_args;
}, 10, 1 );
```

... but I would like to know if there is an option to extend this code to be able to set the categories per seperate widget. E.g. I want a products widget for category 1 on a page x, while I want a products widget for category 2 somewhere else on page x.

I was thinking about using a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) & specifying the category as an array for this shortcode, but not sure on how to implement this.

Any thoughts on this issue?

---

This is the shortcode I tried to use:

```
[productsbycat cat1="broodjes"]
```

& it triggers the following code:

```
function productsbycat_func( $atts ) {
    $categories = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat1' => 'something',
        'cat2' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', function ( $query_args ){

        $query_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $categories,
        ));

        return $query_args;
    }, 10, 1 );
 }

add_shortcode( 'productsbycat', 'productsbycat_func' );
```

However, it does not generate anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Is not possible to extend my code "to be able to set the categories per seperate widget".

**For your shortcode only** I think that you don't need any code customization for that.

I you look to the WooCommerce Official documentation related to [**WooCommerce Shortcodes**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/), you will see on section ["Product category"](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-12) this short code: **`[product_category]`**, which main argument is **`category`**

You can add one product category **slugs** this way:

```
[product_category category="clothing"] // One product category
```

Or for many product categories **slugs** *(coma separated)* this way:

```
[product_category category="posters,music"]
```

The default arguments settings (that you can change) are:

```
$args = array(
    'per_page' => "12",
    'columns' => "4",
    'orderby' => 'title', // or by "menu_order"
    'order' => "asc", // or "desc"
    'category' => "" // Always only product category slugs
    'operator' => "IN" // Possible values are "IN", "NOT IN", "AND".
);
```

> **But it will not work as you would like in your product widgets** as it will display the product grid loop for the defined categories

---

> You should need to build your own widgets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, I was aware of the [product_category] shortcode and I am using this as an alternative now. However, as you mention, I'd like to show the products in a list instead of using a grid, just like the way the products widget does. Hence, my poor attempt to customize the product widget code.

Comment: Hi Loic, I upvoted but as I am quite new to SE, my reputation is not above 15. Therefore, my upvotes are getting recorded but not shown. That’s the message I get when upvoting. Sorry!